# Help me with a simple newsletter subscription form?

Tags: php, forms, email, webforms, newsletter

The newsletter subscription form I am working on can be found in the **footer** at [this link.](http://landingdev.fishlist.com/)

Currently, when the form is submitted, the error/success message displays on a new page.

Instead I would like for the error/success message to display directly below the form in the footer.

IE.  If a user enters the email address name@website.com, the text "Success" should display below the input field instead of on a new page.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's what I've got now:

**In the Header**

```
<script>
function submitEmail() {

    var email = $('#emailText').val();

    jQuery.post('/common/php/send_news.php', {
        email: email
    },function(data){
        $('#submissionResponse').html(data);
    },html);

}
</script>
```

**FORM**

```
<form method="post">
        <fieldset>
        <h3></h3>
        <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" class="input" value="enter your email address..." onfocus="this.className=('input_active')" onblur="this.className=('input')" onclick="this.value='';" />
        <input type="button" name="submit"  value="" class="subscribe_btn" onmouseover="this.className=('subscribe_btn_over')" onmouseout="this.className=('subscribe_btn')" onclick="submitEmail();" />
        <small>*we will not share your email address</small><span class="clear"></span>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
      <div id="submissionResponse"></div>
```

**send_news.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "test@emailtest.com";
    $email_subject = "Newsletter Subscription";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "There was an error with your submission";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(
        !isset($_POST['email'])) {
        died('There was an error with your submission');       
    }

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required


    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thanks for signup up for the Newsletter!

<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is setup a simple page that echos Success or Fail, then pass the information to that page from the form using an Ajax call--You can use jQuery to accomplish this goal.

Add this to the header in either a javascript file, or a script tag:

```
function submitEmail() {

    var email = $('#emailText').val();

    jQuery.post('/submission.php', {
        email: email
    },function(data){
        $('#submissionResponse').html(data);
    },html);

}
```

Then alter the form so that the submission button is like so:

```
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitEmail();" />
```

Then add a div below the form with the id "submissionResponse" like so:

```
<div id="submissionResponse"></div>
```

This way you will be able to handle the post just like you do when you change pages, but you will automatically submit the data and grab the response.

---

ANOTHER EDIT:

While I'm at it, I might as well give another way to do similar. You could, instead of using Ajax, do exactly what you do now, but direct the form to reload the current page (`action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"`) and then at the top of this page add

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    include('submission.php');
}
```

and underneath the form have:

```
<div id="formStatus"><?php echo isset($formStatusResponse) ? $formStatusResponse : null; ?></div>
```

Two ways to accomplish the same goal. Using Ajax is faster, as it only requires the end user to load a single line of text, where as the second method requires the complete reloading of the entire page.

Comment: You could use jQuery, but it isn't really necessary, nor is it significantly shorter than native code. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: jQuery is used to allow for cross browser compatibility. The use of a framework is never required, but it does make coding easier. jQuery allows you to not have to worry about compatibility, nor do you have to worry about remembering all of the nasty little details, it's all bundled into one easy to use function.

Comment: I've also added a secondary method to accomplish the same thing. I still would suggest the Ajax method, but personal preference and knowledge of Javascript might dictate that the second method might be easier to implement.

Comment: All the code is there. submission.php is whatever the filename is that you are using to handle the storage.

Comment: You most likely aren't including a link to the jQuery source files. You can do so by adding `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>` to your webpages header.

Comment: I'm pulling jQuery 1.6 from google in the footer.  I moved it up to the header but that didn't fix it either.  Any other ideas?

Comment: `<input type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" class="input" value="enter your email address..." onfocus="this.className=('input_active')" onblur="this.className=('input')" onclick="this.value='';" />`

Comment: That line of code, you need to add `id="emailText"` because `$('#emailText').val()` is looking for a DOM object with the ID of emailText (the hash sign indicates ID to jQuery)

Comment: still no luck...the error console states "html is not defined" when I click the submit button.  would this have anything to do with it?

Comment: That would be my mistake. I forgot the single quotes in this line `},html);` that should be `},'html');`

Comment: No problem at all. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to do this, you need to use something like an AJAX POST submission, instead of a normal form POST submission. Then you can put the response text anywhere you wish to indicate an error or success condition.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on the specific code necessary to set the AJAX POST submission, and how exactly to set and position the error or success condition?